# Prisma solution to avoid n+1 with findUnique performs mutiple select id from table

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I am using apollo server and nexus with Prisma.
I followed this guide to avoid n+1 problem:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/query-optimization-performance.
This is my `User` type:

```
const User = objectType({
    name: 'User',
    definition(t) {
      t.nonNull.id('id');
      t.nonNull.string('name');
      t.list.field('articles', {
        type: nonNull(Article),
        async resolve(parent, _args, ctx) {
          return ctx.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } }).articles();
        },
      });
      t.list.field('posts', {
        type: nonNull(Post),
        async resolve(parent, _args, ctx) {
          return ctx.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } }).posts();
        },
      });

    },
  });
```

When invoking the following query:

```
query usersByName($names: [String]!) {
  users(names: $names) {
    id
    name
    articles {
      id
      name
    }
    posts {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Prisma performs the following queries:

```
[server] prisma:query SELECT "public"."User"."id", "public"."User"."name" FROM "public"."User" WHERE "public"."User"."id" IN ($1,$2) OFFSET $3
[server] prisma:query SELECT "public"."User"."id" FROM "public"."User" WHERE "public"."User"."id" IN ($1,$2) OFFSET $3
[server] prisma:query SELECT "public"."User"."id" FROM "public"."User" WHERE "public"."User"."id" IN ($1,$2) OFFSET $3
[server] prisma:query SELECT "public"."User"."id" FROM "public"."User" WHERE "public"."User"."id" IN ($1,$2) OFFSET $3
[server] prisma:query SELECT "public"."Article"."id", "public"."Article"."userId", "public"."Article"."name" FROM "public"."Article" WHERE "public"."Article"."userId" IN ($1,$2) OFFSET $3
[server] prisma:query SELECT "public"."Post"."id", "public"."Post"."userId", "public"."Post"."name" FROM "public"."Post" WHERE "public"."Post"."userId" IN ($1,$2) OFFSET $3
```

Why does prisma performs unneeded `SELECT "public"."User"."id" FROM "public"."User"` queries?
How can I avoid that?